# Powershell Grouping acting differently in different versions

Tags: powershell, grouping, piping, versions, powershell-cmdlet

**Question:** How do I write this so it gives the same result in v4 and v5?

I am trying to group the following dataset by `SiteCode`.

I have a dataset as follows [Array of Hashes]:

**Assume `AppointmentId` is always unique**

---

```
$groupedDataset = @{}

$dataset = @(
    @{
        Program          = "x"
        AppointmentId    = "1234567891"
        AdminDate        = "x"
        CountryName      = "x"
        SiteCode         = "x1111"
        DateRequested    = "x"
        SubjectID        = "x"
        AccountID        = "x"  
    },
    @{
        Program          = "x"
        AppointmentId    = "1234567892"
        AdminDate        = "x"
        CountryName      = "x"
        SiteCode         = "x1112"
        DateRequested    = "x"
        SubjectID        = "x"
        AccountID        = "x"  
    },
    @{
        Program          = "x"
        AppointmentId    = "1234567893"
        AdminDate        = "x"
        CountryName      = "x"
        SiteCode         = "x1113"
        DateRequested    = "x"
        SubjectID        = "x"
        AccountID        = "x"  
    },
    @{
        Program          = "x"
        AppointmentId    = "1234567894"
        AdminDate        = "x"
        CountryName      = "x"
        SiteCode         = "x1111"
        DateRequested    = "x"
        SubjectID        = "x"
        AccountID        = "x"  
    }
)
```

When I run the following code below in `PS Version: 5.1`

```
$dataset |
    ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ } |
    Group-Object -Property SiteCode |
    ForEach-Object {
        $groupedDataset[$_.Name] = $_.Group
    }
```

It returns the result I require:

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
x1113                        {@{SiteCode=x1113; Program=x; Appointment...
x1111                        {@{SiteCode=x1111; Program=x; Appointment...
x1112                        {@{SiteCode=x1112; Program=x; Appointment...
```

---

When I run the *exact* code in `PS Version: 4.0` it returns the following:

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
                               {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collect...
```

Comment: Well, I will state the obvious answer...Because they changed the code from one version to the next...

Comment: Yes, @EBGreen I understand that. I need to know which `cmdlet` I have to rework.

Comment: So your question is "How do I write this so it gives the same result in v4 and v5"?

Comment: Yeah. I'll change that now. Just realised I phrased it wrong.

Comment: I get the expected result on v5.1 running: $groupedDataset | Out-Host. Maybe a difference in the default visualizer/outputformatter being used.

Comment: I have production code to be released on a server which runs PS 4.0. I'm not sure it's the formatting because `$_.Name` doesn't output anything when I debug it in `v4.0` but exists in `v5.1`

Comment: Check whether the groups are constructed as expected (without paying attention to the formatting) via: $groupedDataset.Count | out-host and 
$groupedDataset.Values | out-host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell v5.0 improvements have been made, eg. PSCustomObject casting, which is in your script

```
ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ }
```

Try doing it the old school way and instead of building a hashtable yourself, use the one returned by the groupby.

```
$groupedDataset = $dataset |
    ForEach-Object {
         [PSCustomObject]@{
            Program          = $_.Program
            AppointmentId    = $_.AppointmentId
            AdminDate        = $_.AdminDate
            CountryName      = $_.CountryName
            SiteCode         = $_.SiteCode
            DateRequested    = $_.DateRequested
            SubjectID        = $_.SubjectID
            AccountID        = $_.AccountID
        }
    } |
    Group-Object -Property SiteCode -AsHashTable
```

This results in

```
$groupedDataset | out-host

Count Name  Group                                                                                                                                                                                        
----- ----- ------                                                                                                                                                                               
2     x1111 {@{Program=x; AppointmentId=1234567891; AdminDate=x; CountryName=x; SiteCode=x1111; DateRequested=x; SubjectID=x; AccountID=x}, @{Program=x; AppointmentId=1234567894; AdminDate=x; CountryN...
1     x1112 {@{Program=x; AppointmentId=1234567892; AdminDate=x; CountryName=x; SiteCode=x1112; DateRequested=x; SubjectID=x; AccountID=x}}                                                                
1     x1113 {@{Program=x; AppointmentId=1234567893; AdminDate=x; CountryName=x; SiteCode=x1113; DateRequested=x; SubjectID=x; AccountID=x}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, Thanks @pfx :)